# How to analyze a chord from Beethoven sonata no 8 (Pathetique)

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, harmony, analysis

Looking at a chord towards the end of the development in measure 169, beat 2, spelled C♯-E-A♭ over the G pedal.

[image]

How would you analyze this in the context of the harmonic progression at that point?

The best I can come up with is that the C♯/E is a non-harmonic tone leading up to D-F-A♭, a diminished chord with subdominant function.  So the core of the progression is then V-ii(dim)-♭VI-V.

What I'm wondering about is whether the C♯/E/A♭ has a function of its own in the progression.  I might call it a ♭ii(dim) but that doesn't quite feel right.

Comment: Relevant section is at the 6 minute point in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zh6O5vwouXY (the progression gets repeated quite a few times, so there's little chance of missing it)

Comment: Downvoted and deleted my answer.  Why are you asking about chords inside your excerpt?  This is just a long elaboration of the dominant chord.  There isn't really a specific chord in here, but only **V**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole passage is essentially a linear elaboration of V<sup>♭9</sup>. Let's "de-broken-chord" it: it fairly leaps to the eye what Beethoven is doing here when you see the voices.

[image]

Note that we're getting a big A♭-G appoggiatura in the top voice, but the inner voices are marching up and down in minor thirds between the chord tones of the dominant (marked "**+**") in such a way as to sort of tonally center on G: passing tones E/C♯ to suggest an approach from the dominant's dominant, E♭/C to suggest the tonic minor.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to look at it is as you stated as the C♯ and E  as non harmonic tones leading to the D and the F respectively. It could be looked at as a variation of a Neapolitan 6th where the 3rd is minor instead of major that goes to the ii<sup>o</sup> instead of V especially since if you look at it as different enharmonic equivalents of  D♭, F♭, and  A♭ which make D♭m. While this is a possibility keeping the C♯ and E as non-harmonic tones that lead to ii<sup>o</sup> makes more sense, but you can see where the idea for this harmony comes from.

Answer (score 0):

For the upper Bass staff Passing tones stepwise of the voices with unmatched rhythm and staggered resolution. This resolving to a normal G major chord by bar 173. How does Beethoven get away with it? The compass of the uppermost voices spans B natural to B natural with the passing tone movement between the two B's. All the notes having accidentals are merely harmonic coloration. What justification might I have for referring to the inner voices as passing tones? (Thanks to **user16935**'s post the melodic lines are clearly filtered). The low G's (2nd stave) throughout the entire passage suggest to me that Beethoven intends to establish G major while the upper voices veer slightly to notes adjacent to the notes of a G triad.